# Deploy build failed due to not being able to find route path that is there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, react-router, netlify

I've used Netlify with React before and have had no issues deploying a new site until yesterday. I am getting a build fail stating that it: "*Cannot find file '../views/products/products' in './src/routes'.*"

```
5:32:48 PM: Failed to compile.
5:32:48 PM: 
5:32:48 PM: ./src/routes/routes.js
5:32:48 PM: Cannot find file '../views/products/products' in './src/routes'.
```

I'm a bit perplexed as the *products.tsx* file is pointing to the correct path on localhost and I have no issues.

Here is my route component showing the "*import Products*" path:

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../App";
import Product from "../views/product/product";
import Products from "../views/products/products";
import Search from "../views/Search/search";

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route exact path="/products/mens/clothing" component={Products} />
      <Route exact path="/products/mens/packs" component={Products} />
      <Route exact path="/products/womens/clothing" component={Products} />
      <Route exact path="/products/womens/packs" component={Products} />
      <Route exact path="/product/:slug" component={Product} />
      <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Here is a screenshot of the tree:

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix the build error if the path is not broken or am I missing something?

Link to the repo: https://github.com/danlubbers/arcteryx-graphql

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution to get the site to deploy. It appears that Github has the path as: `src/views/Products/products.tsx` and my local has the path as:  `src/views/products/products.tsx`

I don't understand why github is not recognizing the Folder change from Uppercase to Lowercase, so for the mean time, just change my local routes.js path to what github shows: `src/views/Products/products.tsx`

This seems to be more of a GIthub issue instead of a Netlify issue as I previously had thought.

If anyone runs across this thread and knows how to force github to update the folder path, I would like to know.